# Make UITableViewCell not selectable, but make the textfield on it selectable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a static UITableView with 2 rows. I placed a UITextField on those rows for user input. How do I make the UITableViewCells not selectable but still make the UITextField on it user-interactable?

I tried disabling the "User Interaction Enabled" property of the cell in the Inspector pane. As a result, I'm not able to select/highlight the row/cell which is what I want. But I'm not able to interact with the UITextField to input data.

The only solution I can think of right now is to increase the size of the textfield and match the size of the cell so that it completely 'covers' the cell.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not override the method which handles selecting a cell and leave it completely blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT implement, or leave the following delegate method blank:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And disable the selector style for the cell by:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: Awesome. The setSelectionStyle was the one I was looking for. Thanks